# Program menus look bad on KDE

Tags: kde

Until recently I was using the default environment when installing Ubuntu, that is Unity. I just install KDE using the command `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`. When I open programs such as Firefox, LibreOffice, etc., their menus look terrible.

I suspect it has something to do with GTK+, but I don't know how to solve the problem. Is there a package that has not been installed by running the command `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`?

Comment: Would you provide us a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about this issue some time ago; please look it up on [my blog](http://www.gefoo.org/generalfoo/2012/03/25/gtk-using-ugly-theme-in-kde-4-8-1-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric). First, you need to download [gtk-theme-switch [image: Install gtk-theme-switch]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk-theme-switch) and [gtk2-engines-oxygen [image: Install gtk2-engines-oxygen]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk2-engines-oxygen). Then, start up `gtk-theme-switch2` and select `oxygen` as the new theme. After restarting your application, your kde application should look normal again.

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-switch gtk2-engines-oxygen
gtk-theme-switch2
```

Comment: sorry about that, I've edited the post again! Thanks for the correction though